# How can I increase my maximum Health, Stamina and Dead Eye?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

While playing the game for a bit I noticed several notifications that my Health or Stamina or Dead Eye level have increased. But how does that work exactly?

There seems to be a kind of XP system behind it, but I didn't notice any explanation in-game of it. Are the three stats leveled separately or together?

What actions help to increase the maximum level of each of those stats?

Comment: I can't fully because I haven't played it yet but in online previews I've seen, stamina is increased by running around.  There are a lot of RPG elements in the game.

Comment: I can't recall exactly, but it's explained in the in-game menu, under Story > Player

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three attributes are leveled separately. The best way to level these is by completing [challenges](http://www.powerpyx.com/red-dead-redemption-2-how-to-level-up-health-stamina-dead-eye/) (see below for more info).

> You can view your current level under Pause Menu – Player – Your
> Character – Health, Stamina, Dead Eye. Click each attribute and check
> under “Progression” to see your level and XP to the next level up.
>
> Required XP per Level:
>
> - Level 1 = 0 XP
> - Level 2 = 50 XP
> - Level 3 = 100 XP
> - Level 4 = 200 XP
> - Level 5 = 350 XP
> - Level 6 = 550 XP
> - Level 7 = 800 XP
> - Level 8 = 1100 XP
>
> Doing all Challenges gives you 1425 XP per attribute, enough to reach Level 8. That’s where XP progression stops but you can actually bring them to level 10 via outfit sets. The way this works is that every challenge category unlocks a piece of a clothing set after challenge 1, 3, 7, 10. So completing all challenges in a category gets you a complete set consisting of 4 pieces. Equipping all 4 parts grants you +1 skill bar on the attribute (=level 9). Doing ALL 9 challenges (90 tasks) then unlocks another skill bar (=level 10).

According to [this](http://www.pushsquare.com/news/2018/10/guide_red_dead_redemption_2_-_how_to_increase_health_stamina_and_dead_eye) link

> Increasing your maximum health, stamina, and dead eye in Red Dead Redemption 2 is quite straightforward once you know how. It's a simple case of performing specific tasks that grant you xp within each category. Below, we've listed the ways that you can gain xp in health, stamina, and dead eye.
>
> **Health**
>
> - Fist Fights
> - Hunting
> - Fishing
> - Ginseng Elixer
> - Complete Challenges in these categories: Herbalist, Master Hunter, Weapons Expert = 25-150 XP per challenge. A total of 1425 XP for all challenges in these 3 categories
>
> **Stamina**
>
> - Sprinting
> - Swimming
> - Complete Challenges in these categories: Explorer, Horseman, Survivalist = 25-150 XP per challenge. A total of 1425 XP for all challenges in these 3 categories.
>
> **Dead eye**
>
> - Hunting
> - Shooting enemies
> - Cooking
> - Camp chores
> - Complete Challenges in these categories: Bandit, Gambler, Sharpshooter = 25-150 XP per challenge. A total of 1425 XP for all challenges in these 3 categories.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ingame item called **Ginseng Elixir** which permanently increases your health. There are presumably other similar items for Stamina and Dead Eye.